# How can I workaround this capybara/rspec naming collision?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, site-prism

I'm writing a new rspec test case using Capybara (SitePrism actually, which uses Capybara) and I've run into an apparently known issue: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1396. Essentially, due to a change in one or the other, RSpec and Capybara now both have methods named `all`, and when I try to use SitePrism to find a group of elements or SitePrism sections, Capybara invokes the wrong method and returns something of the type `RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All` rather than the expected array of Capybara or SitePrism objects.

For some reason, all my old tests, including many with very similar usage of `sections` and `elements` constructs, work perfectly fine. I'm  having a really hard time finding differences between them that would account for one failing and the other succeeding. I briefly tried rolling back either Capybara or RSpec to just try to make the problem go away for the moment, but it seemed silly, trying to pinpoint when the problem was introduced, when existing test cases that have been running every day never broke.

Can anyone advise me on why one works and the other fails? Here is what these two test cases have in common:

1. Both spec files require the same `spec_helper.rb` file.
2. The `spec_helper.rb` file has both `require rspec` and `require capybara`.
3. Each spec file uses `require_relative` to require a page object used in each test.
4. Each page object file has a `sections :table_rows, <SECTION CLASS>, <ROW CSS>` declaration. They may have different names, classes, and CSS Selectors, but they're the same basic construct.
5. In each spec file, methods are invoked on the page objects that reference `table_rows`.

Referencing `table_rows` in one of these older test cases works just fine, but I'm getting the name collision error in the new test case. Anyone know why that might be, so I can fix the new test case?

Failing that, does anyone know how I can separate things so that the page object requires `capybara` but not `rspec` and the spec file requires `rspec` but not `capybara` to prevent the collision? I don't know much about Ruby package management, but it seems like in order to run an rspec test case that uses a page object, it's all going to be mixed together. I'm not sure of a way to avoid requiring them both.

Failing **that**, does anyone know which versions of either of these two packages I could theoretically use to avoid the issue? I did experiments with rspec 3.2 and capybara 2.4, and neither seemed to work, and I gave up there, because I remembered that no matter how far back in time I go, the test cases I've already written were working fine, and it just seemed silly to try to solve it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Require capybara after Rspec or always call page.all rather than just all

Comment: I already tried changing the order of the requires, and it didn't make a difference. Besides, if the order was important, and I'm using the same `spec_helper` for both tests to require both packages, why does it work with one test case and not the other?

As for `page.all`, unfortunately I'm not calling the `all` method directly. It is called by SitePrism's `elements` and `sections` constructs.

Again, with proposed fixes like these, what really confuses me is why it seems that one test works fine and the other fails, with almost the exact same structure.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace from where its calling the incorrect version of #all?  Also you say it's "almost the exact same structure" - whats the difference that requires the "almost"

Answer (score 0):

Not the best approach, but you can monkey patch the SitePrism::Page class. Here you replace 'all' by 'page.all':

```
SitePrism::Page.class_eval do
  def find_all(*find_args)
    page.all(*find_args)
  end
end
```